# GS function keeps running after RETURN

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

My Google Scripts function keeps running even after returning the next function.

To summarise, I have a function (nightTargetSelection ) that calls another function (dayStart). And as soon as the second function gets called, I want the first one to stop running.

I have stripped down the function and removed everything that should not be relevant for this post. But please let me know if you need more information.

Firstly, I call a user-input form via the following code in GS:

```
function roleWakeUp (roleName, j){ 
  var roleStrAppend = "<div id='id_role_name' style='display:none;'>" + roleName + "</div>";
  var jAppend = "<div id='id_j' style='display:none;'>" + j + "</div>";

  var actionInputDlg = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('night')
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setWidth(600)
  .setHeight(425);

  var wakeUpText = roleName + " wakes up."

  actionInputDlg.append(roleStrAppend).append(jAppend);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(actionInputDlg, wakeUpText);
}
```

Then I have the form submitted by a user via HTML/JS:

```
<script>
selected = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value  
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(selected).nightTargetSelection(selected);
google.script.host.close();
</script>
```

Back in GS, I have the nightTargetSelection (the problematic function that I need helped getting fixed)

```
function nightTargetSelection (selected){      
    return dayStart();
}
```

Finally I have the dayStart function that is called within nightTargetSelection.

```
function dayStart() {
  Browser.msgBox("DAY START");
  //If I do not close the msgBox within 6 minutes (GS timeout period), then nightTargetSelection times out.

roleWakeUp (roleName, j);
}
```

I am expecting that the nightTargetSelection function stops running as soon as dayStart is called.

Unfortunately that is not happening and the nightTargetSelection function only completes when the next nightTargetSelection gets called.

As you can see, dayStart function calls roleWakeUp , making it a loop between functions. I have omitted including the loop details into this question because I dont believe it is relevant. Let me know if it is relevant and I will provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your problem but in this:

```
<script>
      var selected=select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;  
       google.script.run
       .withSuccessHandler(selected)//select is supposed to be a function name
       .nightTargetSelection(selected);
        google.script.host.close();
</script>
```

.withSuccessHandler(functionname or anonymous function)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because `nightTargetSelection()` will not terminate until all of the processes it called have finished or it times out.

Looks like the end of the cycle is `Browser.msgBox("DAY START");`. So allow your server code to finish execution and then use `.withSuccessHandler()` to call `roleWakeUp()` via the client-side script.

(I don't really know what your code is doing. `nightTargetSelection()` seems to be unnecessary given the information you provided. So the example below is an abstraction to show you the flow.)

Client-Side Script

```
<script>
  function yourOriginal() {
    selected = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(restartCycle) // Calls restartCycle() after nightTargetSelection() finishes
      .nightTargetSelection(selected);
    google.script.host.close();
  }

  function restartCycle(values) {
    google.script.run.roleWakeUp(values.roleName, values.j);
  }
</script>
```

Server-Side Scripts

```
function roleWakeUp(roleName, j) {
  // opens the dialog
}

function nightTargetSelection(selected) {      
  return dayStart();
}

function dayStart() {
  Browser.msgBox("DAY START");
  return {"roleName": roleName, "j": j}; // Pass these values to client-side script
}
```

Comment: Diego, thank you for proposing a solution.
Unfortunately I have to keep the order of functions the same because there are a lot of user inputs and IFs between them.
Also some variables I am unable to pass between client and server side (e.g. array of objects).

Is there any way for me to terminate the function without changing the order?

Comment: @IlyaPerelman You will _have_ to change the way you're doing it. A `return` statement will terminate the function, but only after the return statement has finished...which you're using to restart the cycle. You need to figure out how to modify your code so the final values of `daysStart()`, get passed to the client-side function `restartCycle()`. According to the example code, it's only two values. Everything else you need to save somewhere (or pass along with `roleName` and `j`) to be used in the next cycle.

Comment: Diego, thank you for clarification. 
I had to go with another solution to go around my problem - I have broken down the loop with further user inputs to remove the problem with timeout.
Thank you anyway for explaining that there is no way to go around it in the way I originally wanted!